# How to add new class to existing object-detector while preserving the performance on the old classes

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I have an object detector trained on 2 classes.
Now I want to add a new class without annotating the old classes (the new images are annotated with only the new class), But without performance degradation of the existing classes in the detector.

Any suggestions on how it can be done?

(I am using TensorFlow object-detection API based on TF v1.x)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new class to your current model, Unfortunately, it is not possible. Because at the start of your training, you need to define your target class numbers and this determines your model structure.

I have the same issue to add negative examples into my training set. I searched for it and couldn't find a way. Also, model structure made me sure about this idea. You couldn't expect additional class output with model that is not trained on it.